# getColor(int) is deprecated how i can use getColor(int,theme theme)

Tags: android-resources, deprecated, android-color

`getColor(int)` is deprecated .

How can I use `getColor(int, theme theme)`?

I used some lessons and I can't found how I can use `getColor(int, theme theme)`.

Comment: Have you looked at the resources? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something as

```
    ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.red, null)
```

(Prior to API level 23 the theme will not be applied, so it may be `null`.)

Comment: I would suggest using `context.getTheme()` instead of `null` or you might as well just use the deprecated method.